# KDevelop with CMake project - how to manage debug and release builds?

Tags: c++, cmake, kdevelop, kdevelop4

Does KDevelop support switching between debug and release builds for CMake projects?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sure, click **Open configuration** and then **+** at the top of window. This would allow you to add another build directory and you will be able to switch between them.

[image]