# Kdevelop steps and breakpoints not working

Tags: c++, c, breakpoints, kdevelop

I need using steps (Step over, Step over instruction...) and breakpoints.

But the options Step over, Step over instruction and ect. are disabled in menu Run.

And when I put breakpoint into program, program don´t stop on this breakpoint.

I found that I must turn off optimization of compiler and linker. But I don´t know how turn off optimization in Kdevelop 4.4.1.

Where I can find this setting? Or cause of problem with steps and breakpoints is other than compiler optimization?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to compile in debug mode. What toolchain do you use for compiling? CMake? If so, set CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE to Debug.

Comment: And how to setup multiple build configs for release / debug: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15064715/kdevelop-with-cmake-project-how-to-manage-debug-and-release-builds