# How to step into OpenCV functions on Ubuntu in KDevelop?

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu, kdevelop

I have installed OpenCV on my Ubuntu, and it works well. My problem is that I cannot manage to step into OpenCV's functions when debugging, if I press F11, it does not enter the functions, it is like Windows with no debug build. It is possible that I have not build OpenCV with DEBUG flag on. How to do it and how to do the step in its functions?

Comment: I am using KDevelop, it is written in the question...

Comment: OpenCV should be removed from this quesiton, should be the same for every library.

Comment: I do not reproduce on KDevelop 4.7.3, Ubuntu 16.04: F11 does step into, and F10 over. Please produce a minimal example project and give a precise KDevelop / OS version ;-) For CMake projects, use `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug` as mentioned at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24322956/kdevelop-steps-and-breakpoints-not-working

Answer (score 1):

You can use debuggers like GDB. If you are using IDEs like Eclipse CDT then you need to manually update the build settings.

I found the OpenCV  [reference document](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_eclipse/linux_eclipse.html).

Comment: Thanks, but I mentioned in the question that I am using KDevelop