# KDevelop can't debug in ubuntu?

Tags: c, ubuntu, kdevelop

i am a new to KDevelop.
I am using ubuntu to develop C.

My problems as follows:
I have already trigger breakpoint in KDevelop. After I click F9.  The KDevelop just show "*****Exit normally******".  I am not quite sure what the problem it is?

Looks Like I can't debug.

And I can't see the print.
[image]

Comment: Maybe try to print a "\n" in there somewhere or flush sometimes.

Comment: No, with a debugger it should definitely stop on the five break points he set. I don't know how KDevelop handles debuggers, but maybe you need to setup a debugger first in the settings?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kdevelop steps and breakpoints not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24322956/kdevelop-steps-and-breakpoints-not-working)

Answer (score 7):

Check the CMakeLists.txt.
In my case,
even in Project-> Open Configuration...
I make CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE as Debug,
but in CMakeLists.txt is Release,
the build still uses Release mode.
Hopefully it is helpful.

Answer (score 5):

Go to *Run* -> *Configure Launches*, *[Add New...]* -> *Compiled Binary*, select  *Debug* on the left side, *Debugger executable:* and select `/usr/bin/gdb`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Assuming that you are using gcc for the compile and link steps, the compile step needs to have -gdb3 or similar parameter so debugging info is available to the debugger.

Comment: Since your using gdb, the source code also needs to be visible to the gdb debugger

Comment: When I open the  [Add New...] ,there isn't "Compile Binary", there is only have :Application,Plasmold Launcher,script Application.

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks.