# Do you have to create 2 separate projects for debug and release in kdevelop?

Tags: kdevelop

For some reason it asks me if I want a debug or release kind of project when I create it, so I can't just switch between those 2 in one project. Do need to have 2 separate projects for debug and release?

Comment: Good question. You can chose the build type when right-clicking on project. Not sure if you have to do this every time or if there's a nicer way of doing it. Would be nice if someone who knows their way around KDevelop could help answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This stems from the way how CMake works (to be precise, how CMake works with Makefile generator): it requires separate build directory for each build type.

I'm not sure what you mean by "having 2 separate projects", but intended way to do this is to select `Project -> Open Configuration...` menu for your project, go to `CMake` tab, and then click `+` button to add another build dir. Then you configure new build dir with the build type you want.

Comment: Also have a look at this similar post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15064715/kdevelop-with-cmake-project-how-to-manage-debug-and-release-builds